# Starting navigator in Angular, using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: angular, navigator

When I create a project of type "Projet Autonome TypeScript Angular", it wants to start the execution on Edge.

How can I correct that big bug ?
It would be interesting, as other aspects of the project type are OK.
I searched "Edge" in the whole project, but found nothing.
A search of the project type name on Internet gave nothing.

Edge asked for an update, so I uninstalled it. It ... does not work better.

I develop on Windows 11 using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition.